# How to display daily pictures for each day in a month using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to display daily pictures everyday of the month using javascript. This is the code that I wrote but it doesn't display any picture! Which part of my code should I change?

Please guide me. Thanks a lot.

```
<script>
<!--
var imlocation = "/Popularity/images/"

var today_obj=new Date()
var today_date=today_obj.getDate()

var image=new ImageArray()


image[0] = 'popularity5.png'
image[1] = 'popularity6.png'
image[2] = 'popularity6.png'
image[3] = 'popularity7.png'
image[4] = 'popularity6.png'
image[5] = 'popularity7.png'
image[6] = 'popularity7.png'
image[7] = 'popularity8.png'
image[8] = 'popularity7.png'
image[9] = 'popularity6.png'
image[10] = 'popularity6.png'
image[11] = 'popularity7.png'
image[12] = 'popularity8.png'
image[13] = 'popularity7.png'
image[14] = 'popularity5.png'
image[15] = 'popularity6.png'
image[16] = 'popularity6.png'
image[17] = 'popularity7.png'
image[18] = 'popularity6.png'
image[19] = 'popularity7.png'
image[20] = 'popularity7.png'
image[21] = 'popularity8.png'
image[22] = 'popularity7.png'
image[23] = 'popularity6.png'
image[24] = 'popularity6.png'
image[25] = 'popularity7.png'
image[26] = 'popularity8.png'
image[27] = 'popularity7.png'
image[28] = 'popularity6.png'
image[29] = 'popularity7.png'
image[30] = 'popularity8.png'
image[31] = 'popularity7.png'


document.write('<img src="+imlocation+image[today_date]+">')

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: What does the output on the page look like? Does that give you any clue?

Comment: @csmckelvey output page is white without anything!

Comment: Look at the quotes in your `document.write()`, and how stackoverflow is highlighting the contents.

Comment: `var image=new ImageArray()`: surely that should be `new Array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
var image=new ImageArray()
```

to:

```
var image= [];
```

And, fix the quotes in the `document.write()`.

```
document.write('<img src="' + path + '">')
```

To make it easier, put the path together in a variable first and, rather than write out new HTML elements by concatenating strings, just include the element on the page to begin with and then you only need to modify the `src` and `alt` attributes, which removes the need to concatenate (and use the ancient `document.write()`) altogether.

```js
var imlocation = "/Popularity/images/"
var today_date = new Date().getDate();
var path = imlocation + today_date;

var image= [];

image[0] = 'popularity5.png'
image[1] = 'popularity6.png'
image[2] = 'popularity6.png'
image[3] = 'popularity7.png'
image[4] = 'popularity6.png'
image[5] = 'popularity7.png'
image[6] = 'popularity7.png'
image[7] = 'popularity8.png'
image[8] = 'popularity7.png'
image[9] = 'popularity6.png'
image[10] = 'popularity6.png'
image[11] = 'popularity7.png'
image[12] = 'popularity8.png'
image[13] = 'popularity7.png'
image[14] = 'popularity5.png'
image[15] = 'popularity6.png'
image[16] = 'popularity6.png'
image[17] = 'popularity7.png'
image[18] = 'popularity6.png'
image[19] = 'popularity7.png'
image[20] = 'popularity7.png'
image[21] = 'popularity8.png'
image[22] = 'popularity7.png'
image[23] = 'popularity6.png'
image[24] = 'popularity6.png'
image[25] = 'popularity7.png'
image[26] = 'popularity8.png'
image[27] = 'popularity7.png'
image[28] = 'popularity6.png'
image[29] = 'popularity7.png'
image[30] = 'popularity8.png'
image[31] = 'popularity7.png'

var img = document.getElementById("picOfTheDay");
img.src = path;
img.alt = path;
```

```html
<img id="picOfTheDay">
```

Now, if your images will all be the same file name, but only differ by their number, which will correspond to the date, then you don't even need the array and can do this much more simply.

If you want to have different images on a month-by-month basis, you could create numbered folders that correspond to the month (starting from zero) and then just put the correct amount of properly named images in each folder.

```
root
  /Popularity
    /images
      /0                    // <-- January
        /popularity1.jpg
        /popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        /popularity31.jpg
      /1                    // <-- February
        /popularity1.jpg
        /popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        /popularity28.jpg
      /2                    // <-- March
        /popularity1.jpg
        /popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        /popularity31.jpg
```

```js
var today = new Date();  // Get today

// Create path with month number as folder and date injected in image:
var path = "/Popularity/images/" + today.getMonth() + "/popularity" + today.getDate() + ".png" ;

var img = document.getElementById("picOfTheDay");  // Locate the pre-existing image element
img.src = path;  // Set the source
img.alt = path;  // Set the alternate text
```

```html
<img id="picOfTheDay">
```

Comment: thanks @ScottMarcus it had affected. but now in output page it shows wrong src of the images. its : +imlocation+image[today_date]+

Comment: I fixed it successfully. Thanks a lot

Comment: another question if for example I want to put for 3 month how will be ?

Comment: @Lili You'll need to get the month as well as the date and have the appropriate amount of images in your array.

Comment: can you please write me how will be for month ?

Comment: @Lili `new Date().getMonth()`. But note that `.getMonth()` starts at 0. (January === 0, December === 11).

Comment: I appreciate it if you can write an completely answer for me for 3 month similar of my code was for 1 month.

Comment: @Lili I will update the answer, but please understand that your original question has been answered. If you have additional questions, you should post a new question. And, you should first give it a try on your own with the new information I've given you.

Comment: @Lili Answer updated. As you can see, when you run it, it produces `/Popularity/images/0/popularity30.png`. So, if you had a folder called "0" (for January) you would then have 31 images (properly numbered) in that folder. Then, you'd have a folder named `1` (for February) and have 28 properly numbered images in that folder and so on.

Comment: how will be this parts ? `image[0] = 'popularity5.png'
image[1] = 'popularity6.png'
image[2] = 'popularity6.png'
image[3] = 'popularity7.png'`

Comment: @Lili I don't know what you are asking. As I've shown, you do not need an array of images at all.

Comment: how should i change the image[ ] for 3 month ?

Comment: @Lili Please read the last part of my answer. You do not need an image array at all - there will not be any `image[]`. The second part of my answer fully explains how to set this up for 3 months with just 5 lines of code.

Comment: `/0                    // <-- January
        popularity1.jpg
        popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        popularity31.jpg
      /1                    // <-- February
        popularity1.jpg
        popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        popularity28.jpg
      /3                    // <-- March
        popularity1.jpg
        popularity2.jpg
          . . .
        popularity31.jpg`

Comment: why you wrote 0 1 3 ?

Comment: @Lili I've already explained that in an earlier comment. *new Date().getMonth(). But note that .getMonth() starts at 0. (January === 0, December === 11)*

Comment: @Lili And, I indicated that 0 is your January folder, 1 is your February folder and 2 would be your March folder.

Comment: why you didn't use 2 ?

Comment: @Lili LOL. Ah, well, that was a typo!

Comment: then with this code of you it means even i can write for all 12 month ?

Comment: @Lili Yes. You'd just have to set up 12 folders with the appropriate number of images in each folder.

Comment: wow! Excellent! then don't update this answer till i can have here your code

Comment: is it possible to write texts for 1 month similar this code ? but to be for example 5 or 10 different texts that for example 1 user with second user receive different text or image in same day ?

Comment: my meaning is for example on 31 of January everyone will receive "Text1" , Is it possible to write some texts in 31 of January that everyone receive different texts ?

Comment: Anything is possible. You should post a new question that clearly states what you are looking for and also try to write a solution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you should use an absolute path?

```
var imlocation = "/Popularity/images/"
```

means you have a folder named Popularity under root.

```
 var imlocation = "Popularity/images/"
```

means that you have a folder named Popularity in the same location (folder) as your html document.

You can easily check what the problem with your code is, by right clicking the browser and clicking inspect. Please do so and tell us whats written there, so that we can help better

Edit: also your document.write('') is broken

Since everything you writevis between simple quotes the browser threats the entire text as a string. Try this:

```
 write('<img src=" ' +imlocation+image[today_date]+' ">')
```

note that I added two single quotes

Also, as pointed out by others. new ImageArray() should be new Array()

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your last line to this:

```
document.write('<img src="' + imlocation + image[today_date] + '">');
```

Also please use semicolons at the end of the lines.